# How can you prevent build artifact downloads in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I am setting up the security for our team city build server. I would like all users to be able to view all builds, some of these builds produce artifacts with sensitive data in (connection strings and the like). Is it possible to prevent a particular role from viewing build artifacts?

Comment: I have no idea. 5 1/2 years is a long time, I can barely remember what I did yesterday ;)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bit of a workaround, but what about if you had two builds in a [build chain](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Chain)? The first *produces* the artifacts but doesn't publish them and would be visible to all users; the second doesn't have any build steps and just publishes your sensitive artifacts.
Would that work in your case?